# How to solve the multiple integral $\int\sin^{p-2}(\theta_1)\sin^{p-3}(\theta_2) \cdots \sin(\theta_{p-2})\ d\theta_1d\theta_2\cdots d\theta_{p-1}$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am wondering how to solve the multiple integrals of this form:

$$
\int_{\theta_1 \in [0,\pi]}\ldots\int_{\theta_{p-2} \in [0,\pi]}\int_{\theta_{p-1} \in [0,2\pi]} \sin^{p-2}(\theta_1)\sin^{p-3}(\theta_2) \cdots \sin^{2}(\theta_{p-3}) \sin(\theta_{p-2})\ \ \  d\theta_1d\theta_2\cdots d\theta_{p-1}
$$

Here, the first $p-2$ integrals go from $[0,\pi]$ while the last goes from $[0,2\pi]$. I was wondering if there was a simple way to solve the integral. Thanks.

How to solve the multiple integral $\int\sin^{p-2}(\theta_1)\sin^{p-3}(\theta_2) \cdots \sin(\theta_{p-2})\ \ \  d\theta_1d\theta_2\cdots d\theta_{p-1}$

Comment: Unless I'm reading it incorrectly, the integral is separable for every new variable. For example, $∫∫ \sin(x)\sin(y) dydx = ∫ \sin(x) dx ∫ \sin(y) dy$

Comment: For $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$, $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$ for $n\ \texttt{odd}$. It's likely your integral $vanishes\ out$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

This is the area element of $n$ sphere. It is not hard to prove by induction that the integral is
$$
S_{n-1} = \frac{2 \pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}
$$

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element)